# Inside cellForRowAtIndexPath, saving cell to @property, always last cell in tableview

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

Using the following delegate method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    PLOTCheckinTableViewCell *cell = (PLOTCheckinTableViewCell *)[self.checkinsTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CheckinCellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    [cell setSwipeGestureWithView:crossView color:redColor mode:MCSwipeTableViewCellModeSwitch state:MCSwipeTableViewCellState2 completionBlock:^(MCSwipeTableViewCell *cell, MCSwipeTableViewCellState state, MCSwipeTableViewCellMode mode) {
        self.indexPathToDelete = [tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Delete?"
                                                                    message:@"Are you sure your want to remove this checkin?"
                                                                   delegate:self
                                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"No"
                                                          otherButtonTitles:@"Yes", nil];
        [alertView show];
        }];
}
```

Then inside the `UIAlertView` delegate method:

```
- (void)alertView:(UIAlertView *)alertView clickedButtonAtIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex {

// No
if (buttonIndex == 0) {

}

// Yes
else {
    PLOTCheckinTableViewCell *cell = (PLOTCheckinTableViewCell *)[self.checkinsTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.indexPathToDelete];
    [self.checkins removeObjectAtIndex:self.indexPathToDelete.row];
    [self.checkinsTableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[self.indexPathToDelete] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    self.indexPathToDelete = nil;
}
```

}

However, whenever I hit "Ok" in the alert view, the cell that's deleted is always the last one in the tableview, ie. not the cell the user actually swiped.

Is it something to do with the dequeuing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You should not be referencing to your cell. Instead, try to reference to the actual object that caused the cell to exist (i.e. if this is a list of messages, the message that is displayed within that cell).

The cell object is being reused and the UIAlertView wont know about that. Even if you have 1000 items in your list, you are not going to have more than 20 cells. They are always going to be reused thorough your table view scrolling.

You should be looking into removing an element from your data source array instead of removing the cell itself. After removing the element, you can always reload your table view to visually reflect the elemnt removed state.

Comment: So what's my best method of knowing which cell is being acted upon? ie. to then access my datasource array

Comment: You should know which element your cell is referring to inside your cellForRowAtIndexPath. You should be able to access your element with indexPath.row (and indexPath.section), something  like [sourceArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]. Once you have your element, link it to your UIAlertView. You could use the delegate property but I think it would make more sense to maybe subclass UIAlertView and link your element to a new attribute.